# Is "Are there existing formal standards targeted to airbag controlling software?" on-topic on "Programmers"?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Is the following an on-topic question on Programmers?

> Are there existing formal standards targeted to airbag controlling
>   software?

I think for example at IEC 62304. To give a bit of context: I asked myself the question after browsing at http://www.hovding.com/

I asked a [similar question at meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269158/15485) and they suggested to ask also here at meta.programmers... they told me that cross-posting between meta sites is acceptable.

Comment: No, but I think "What are formal standards targeted to airbag controlling software?" would be on-topic.

Comment: @user11153 as far as I can tell, changing to "what are blah-blah" would pull the question under [recommend off-site resource](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487) close reason

Comment: What is leading you to ask this question? Perhaps _that_ is the real question to ask here.

Comment: @Snowman As I wrote in the question, I was browsing a web site of an airbag for head protection in bicycle activities; the web site has information regarding the CE marking (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking) of the airbag and about the European Norm EN 1078:1997 but no information about the compliance of the airbag triggering software to some standard or norm.

Answer (score 5):

This question can be answered with either "Yes" or "No".  Neither of those are good answers.

The ability to find an answer for this doesn't draw from expert knowledge of programmers, but rather that of regulators, lawyers, and [research librarians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Librarian#Positions_and_duties) (read the paragraph beginning with "Reference or research librarians help people doing research to find the information they need").

The primary skills here are google-fu.  Furthermore, those who do not have access to something that isn't likely an [open standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_standard) can only say "I can't find it if it is" - also a poor answer.

As such, this question doesn't fit the Stack Exchange model for Q&A.

On P.SE, it would get closed as:

> Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

(please read [Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487) - the section beginning "Asking for a link to something or statistics").

Comment: oh, so that's essentially a [question with yes/no answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773)! _'Almost all yes/no questions I've seen... should be edited into a question that isn't really asking for just a yes/no, it should be asking to *explain* something... Note that just adding "Explain" at the end isn't really a good way to go about this; you should refactor the question on a more fundamental level.'_

Comment: @gnat and changing the question to a more open question turns it into "What are the formal standards...?"

Comment: @ratchetfreak that would still be a problematic one in that it remains a google-fu question that is best answered by regulators, lawyers, and research librarians.

Comment: @ratchetfreak good observation. That way would be wrong way, either ([list questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/list-questions/info)). Wonder if it's at all possible to _refactor_ such a question as recommended in MSE post I quoted above